# angularJS get class name from ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this html page:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="HomeController as home">
    <section class="tile-column large-2 columns" ng-repeat="container in home.menu" id="{{ container.id }}" tile-column>
        <h1 class="column-title" ng-bind="container.name"></h1>
        <a class="tile {{ tile.classes }}" href="{{ tile.action }}" id="{{ tile.id }}" tile="{{ tile.colour }}" ng-repeat="tile in container.tiles">
            <i class="fa {{ tile.icon }}"></i>
            <span class="title">{{ tile.name }}</span>
        </a>
    </section>
</div>
```

The home controller looks like this:

```
// ---
// CONTROLLERS.
// ---

.controller('HomeController', ['Menu', function (menu) {
    var self = this;

    self.menu = menu.current;
}])

// ---
// SERVICES.
// ---

.factory('MenuService', function () {
    var get = function () {
        return [{
            id: 'items',
            name: 'Items',
            tiles: [{
                id: 'customer-services',
                name: 'Customer services',
                action: '/customer-services',
                icon: 'fa-arrow-circle-down',
                classes: 'x-large',
                colour: 'pink'
            }, {
                id: 'distribution',
                name: 'Distribution',
                action: '/distribution',
                icon: 'fa-arrow-circle-down',
                colour: '#000000'
            }, {
                id: 'compaints',
                name: 'Complaints',
                action: '/complaints',
                icon: 'fa-arrow-circle-down',
                colour: ''
            }, {
                id: 'sampling',
                name: 'Sampling',
                action: '/sampling',
                icon: 'fa-arrow-circle-down',
                colour: ''
            }, {
                id: 'manufacturing',
                name: 'Manufacturing',
                action: '/manufacturing',
                icon: 'fa-arrow-circle-down',
                colour: ''
            }, {
                id: 'warehousing',
                name: 'Warehousing',
                action: '/warehousing',
                icon: 'fa-arrow-circle-down',
                colour: ''
            }, {
                id: 'finance',
                name: 'Finance',
                action: '/finance',
                icon: 'fa-arrow-circle-down',
                colour: ''
            }]
        }, {
            id: 'configuration',
            name: 'Configuration',
            tiles: [{
                id: 'profile',
                name: 'Profile',
                action: '/security/profile',
                icon: 'fa-arrow-circle-down',
                colour: ''
            }, {
                id: 'signout',
                name: 'Sign out',
                action: '/security/logout',
                icon: 'fa-arrow-circle-down',
                colour: ''
            }]
        }];
    };

    return {
        get: get
    };
})

// ---
// MODELS.
// ---

.factory('Menu', ['MenuService', function (service) {
    var get = function () {
        if (Modernizr.localstorage) { // If we have local storage
            var items = angular.fromJson(localStorage['items']); // Try to get our menu items

            if (items) // If we have a result
                return items; // Return our items
        }

        return service.get(); // Otherwise return our default
    };

    var save = function (menu) {
        if (Modernizr.localstorage) { // If we have local storage
            localStorage['items'] = angular.toJson(menu); // Store this class

            current = get(); // Get the latest changes
        }
    }

    var current = get();

    return {
        current: current,
        save: save
    };
}]);
```

As you can see, the tiles have classes in the model.
What I want to do, is have a directive that can check the classes of each tile.
I have this currently set up:

```
.directive('xLarge', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            console.log('this should work on an extra large tile');
        }
    }
})
```

which I would expect to fire once, but it never gets hit.
Can anyone think of how I would get this directive to work?

Comment: Plunkr available here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Z3uMrUXLCWjEU4h6XH7W?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding the directive by class you could do it using a custom element:

http://plnkr.co/edit/fLBb8GqKCFLekBLHTokX?p=preview

```
  <div class="row" ng-controller="HomeController as home">
    <section class="tile-column large-2 columns" ng-repeat="container in home.menu" id="{{ container.id }}" tile-column="">
      <h1 class="column-title" ng-bind="container.name"></h1>
      <test tile="tile" ng-repeat="tile in container.tiles">
        <a class="tile {{ tile.classes }}" tile="{{ tile.colour }}" id="{{ tile.id }}" href="{{ tile.action }}">
          <i class="fa {{ tile.icon }}"></i>
          <span class="title">{{ tile.name }}</span>
        </a>
      </test>
    </section>
  </div>
```

Sample directive:

```
.directive('test', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          tile: '=tile'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            console.log('this should work on an extra large tile');
            console.log(scope.tile);
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: I am only trying to target the elements with the "x-large" class because those are the ones that have to have some logic applied

Comment: Could you describe the logic you're trying to apply? If you need to render the contents of the tile differently you may find it as easy to just use ng-if inside ng-repeat

Comment: sure, the directive will be checking the width of the extra large tile and then applying it to the height. This will change on browser resize.

Comment: Would a CSS Media Query suffice?: http://plnkr.co/edit/UcH1rR3HdHNhYiLoewJ8?p=preview (resize the browser above/below 992px wide)